# How to Pass Extra Parameters for Multiplayer games in Google Play Games Services?

Tags: android, google-play-games, multiplayer

Im presently coding a real time multiplayer game with Google Play Games Services. The 1st player can select a game with the given options.

- Vehicle: ship or boat
- Danger: sharks or octopus

So, when Player1 sends the invitation, and it is accepted by the 2nd player- How should i pass this information to Player2 as an extra parameter. Hence if player1 selected Ship & Sharks, when player2 starts the game, the game loads these options(ie Ship & Sharks). 
Is there any Logic to handle a case like this?

Comment: Can you confirm if Player 1 and Player 2 uses the same device or different device on both players?

Comment: Player1 and player2 are two separate individuals. They have their own devices. The logic implementation is what I couldn't find. How does Player2's phone on receiving the invite, know it would have load a game with the same options Player1 had chosen before sending the invite. This is for RealTime Multiplayer

Comment: did you solve this? If not you could try sending a reliableMessage(high chance of getting delivered then unReliableMessage) in the `onPeersConnected()` callback, that is after both players have connected. In order for the other player to receive the game options sent, you will retrieve the message in the `OnRealTimeMessageReceivedListener` where it will come in form of bytes and you can convert it into a string to get the game options sent.

Comment: Yeah Bryan, that's what I finally did. I let all info load in the first transfer, and then go ahead with the game. At the end I will be honest I think Google Game play services has a long way to go before it becomes an admired service. I'm not boasting but Ive built a way better interaction with my own NodeJs + socketIO. The amount of time one wastes with implementing the lost logic of Google Play Games is ridiculous!